# ReactJS - Best practice to render conditional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am quite new to react and like it, but the flexibility gives me some headaches what the best practices are.

For example I have this component, a conditional Login Button.

```
  const dynamicLogin = () => {
    if (ctx.isLoggedIn) {
      return (
        <button
          className="bg-gray-600 px-8 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-800"
          onClick={ctx.onLogout}
        >
          Logout
        </button>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <button
          className="bg-gray-600 px-8 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-800"
          onClick={ctx.onLogin}
        >
          Login
        </button>
      );
    }
  };
```

I render it by calling the function is my `return` statement.

```
  return (
    <div>
      {ctx.visible ? <Warenkorb></Warenkorb> : ""}

      <nav className="flex justify-between px-4 bg-red-400 text-white text-xl fixed top-0 left-0 w-full">
        <div>
          <h3 className="p-4 inline">
            {ctx.isLoggedIn ? "Eingeloggt!" : "Not Logged In"}
          </h3>
          {dynamicLogin()}
        </div>
        {dynamicWarenkorb()}
...
```

To be honest, the syntax begins to look quite messi, but it somewhat works. But calling a function inside the return statement feels VERY WRONG. Is the way I render my Components fine or is there a better/faster way to do it. The documentation seems not to be too helpful, because most of the stuff is about class based components :-/.

Comment: The way I've seen it would be that Warenkorb would take props that indicate if it should render or return null. Same for your other one for logged in - you'd have a component that takes a prop and it either renders content or null. This question is likely to be closed as opinion based.  =)

Comment: In general, calling a function inside the JSX is an (unfortunately common) anti-pattern. A function is just a component. Make your function a component and pass the appropriate props. While some poeple think it's unnecessary, the benefit you get out of it is better separation of concerns and smaller components overall. Before you had one component that had multiple "helper render" functions, and now you have several smaller components. It's just easier to read. This is, as with any best practice, my opinion only. Go ahead and try the pattern of turning `dynamicLogin` into `<DynamicLogin/>`

Comment: There is a [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) on the topic and a few ways to tackle it. "it is up to you to choose an appropriate style based on what you and your team consider more readable. Also remember that whenever conditions become too complex, it might be a good time to extract a component."

Comment: I generally agree with @Adam, but sometimes you want a quick and dirty solution. A `<Table>` component, for example. You can go through the hassle of creating `<Row>` and `<Cell>` components but sometimes it's easier to call a function that exists in that component that does a quick compilation and spits out some JSX. But like he said, very opinionated. I've used both methods, and both sit fine with me. Mostly it comes down to how/if you're testing your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using components is cleaner than functions in instances like this. For example, you could create an `AuthButton` component as such:

```
export function AuthButton({ ctx }) {
  if (ctx.loggedIn) {
    return (
      <button
        className="bg-gray-600 px-8 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-800"
        onClick={ctx.onLogout}
      >
        Logout
      </button>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <button
      className="bg-gray-600 px-8 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-800"
      onClick={ctx.onLogin}
    >
      Login
    </button>
  );
}
```

Then you can call it in your other component:

```
import { AuthButton } from './AuthButton';

function OtherComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      {ctx.visible ? <Warenkorb></Warenkorb> : ""}

      <nav className="flex justify-between px-4 bg-red-400 text-white text-xl fixed top-0 left-0 w-full">
        <div>
          <h3 className="p-4 inline">
            {ctx.isLoggedIn ? "Eingeloggt!" : "Not Logged In"}
          </h3>
          <AuthButton ctx={ctx} />
        </div>
        {dynamicWarenkorb()}
      </nav>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it, you can place the following piece of code right where you called the function and get rid of the rest

```
{ctx.isLoggedIn ? (
        <button
          className="bg-gray-600 px-8 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-800"
          onClick={ctx.onLogout}
        >
          Logout
        </button>
) : (
       <button
          className="bg-gray-600 px-8 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-800"
          onClick={ctx.onLogin}
        >
          Login
        </button>
)}
```